# Why does this C# timer not fire? (Interval set based on current and picked time)

Tags: c#

i am trying to set the tick alert for the timer based on the time set by the datetime picker. however i dont get the tick alert at all.

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value >= DateTime.Now)
    {
        sendOrder.Interval =(int) (dateTimePicker1.Value.Ticks-DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        sendOrder.Enabled = true;
    }
```

in the above code, i set the tick time based on difference between time from datetimepicker - current time. what am i doing wrong on this one?

Comment: What is the value of `dateTimePicker1.Value.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks`?

Comment: Where is the code that specifies what function is called in the alert? What kind of Timer are you using? There are 3 kinds in .NET

Comment: Can you show a little more information on what you are trying to do like how you are using the timer. I am assuming this is a windows forms timer not a thread timer from the use in the small code snippet.

Comment: And I don't know any timer that accepts `ticks` as interval

Comment: @KendallFrey, based on the code, I think it's `System.Timers.Timer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `System.Timers.Timer`, Interval is in milliseconds, whereas you are specifying ticks. There are 10,000 ticks in 1 millisecond.

Try this instead:

```
sendOrder.Interval = (int)(dateTimePicker1.Value.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks) / 10000;
```

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.Ticks Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx):

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

[Timer.Interval Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx):

> The time, in milliseconds

So your timer is firing; the interval is just off by a factor of 10,000.

Instead of twiddling with ticks, you can use the [TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) to get the difference between the two [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values in milliseconds:

```
sendOrder.Interval = (dateTimePicker1.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: You are changing your answer every second already to be the first.I forgot which version it was :)

Comment: What are you trying to say? Do whatever you want. In one of your answers, you applied `TotalMilliseconds` to long and I downvoted. I won't cancel my downvote since I don't like these types of answers just to be the first.

Comment: I understand you want to be the one who says the last word but `long.TotalMilliseconds` doesn't require much explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`Ticks` is in intervals of 100 nanoseconds.  There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.  `Interval` is in milliseconds.  So that is obviously an error.